# how to get accurate geofencing event

Tags: android, location, android-geofence

Trying to monitor the device enter or exit the geofence. but sometime it receives the enter or exit event even the device is not moving. code snippet are below.

Also noticed after using the

```
lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

to create the geofence, then in

```
void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

and use the updated location to get the distance between the location used for geofence, seems it is also not accurate. Like when walked only a few steps away after created the geofence from location #1,  the onLocationChanged() returns location #2 and the distanceTo() returns shows over 200 meters.

Also noticed even the device is on the table without moving, the onLocationChanged(Location location) returns different locations sometime.

I guess it may depends on the provider, but the test is within wifi covered area. Maybe it is how it works.

But what if it is required to get more accurate or granular, is there a different or better way to get more accurate geofence event, or accurate current location?

```
 googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
createGeofence(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()));
```

after the geofence is created, even the device is put on the table without move, it receives Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER  and  Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT periodically. Sometime it stays still without event, but it will receive those events if slightly move the device a bit.

```
private void createGeofence(LatLng latlng) {
    GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient; mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);

        Geofence geofence = makeOneGeofence(GEOFENCE_REQUEST_ID, latlng, 150f); 
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);

        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                geofenceRequest,
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
}

Geofence makeOneGeofence(String reqestId, LatLng latLng, float radius) {
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(reqestId)
            .setCircularRegion(
                    latLng.latitude,
                    latLng.longitude,
                    radius  //radius, meters   
            ).setExpirationDuration(60 * 60 * 1000)  //1 hr
             .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                    Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL |
                    Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .setLoiteringDelay(500000)  // 500 secs, after user enters a geofence if the user stays inside during this period of time
            .build();
}

private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL )
            .addGeofence( geofence )
            .build();
}

private final int GEOFENCE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {

    if ( mGeofencePendingIntent != null )
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(
            this, GEOFENCE_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GPS signal varies between devices and also behave different if your device's GPS signal is bad (if you're inside a building or something like that) you would see that the the GPS position is jumping around and is not constant. 
Currently there is not good way to get accurate location in 100% of the cases.

Comment: Thanks Sagi Mymon! But there might be some way since some apps seem work pretty reliably with the LocationServices. Just wondering if someone may know.